# php json encode format

Tags: php, mysql, json, format

I have simple code

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from wizard"); 

    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $rows[] = $r;       
    }
    echo json_encode($rows);
```

My result

> [{"0":"1","id":"1","1":"121","fid":"121","2":"4","meth_id":"4","3":"A",

instead of

> [{"id":"1","fid":"121","meth_id":"4",

What is the problem of such kind of format and how can I fix it.

Thank you

Comment: Can you `print_r($r);`?

Comment: Have you also tried to check the dump of 'wizard'? Please show the input to us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the second `result_type` parameter with value `MYSQL_ASSOC` when calling mysql_fetch_array.

```
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
```

Otherwise, `MYSQL_BOTH` default value is used, and you get an array with both associative and number indices http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php, thus your duplicated values in the result array.

And also you are discouraged to use deprecated mysql_* functions, and using instead [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), but that's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check whether the result got in json_encode is an array.Try using `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_fetch_array` .